# Probability distributed man in bar

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read years ago and only remember hazily. Still I'm often reminded of it whenever a see a guy in a film propping up the end of a bar. I must have read it while at college perhaps 1980s though it was definitely older.

The POV belongs to a patron in a bar. He sits at the end of the bar and observes. Some time before he was involved in an accident of some kind (perhaps a physics experiment) which split up his physical integrity on this plane allowing him to flow around and coalesce in various places, such as the bar, temporarily. It was a probability related problem. I think it had a noir style and was fairly short.

I don't remember action or plot, or if it had any. That's a bit vague but it's all I remember.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of Larry Niven's ["For a Foggy Night"](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v041n01_1971-07_PDF/page/n65/mode/2up?view=theater) but only vaguely. No physics experiment.

Comment: Sounds like a Rudy Rucker story

Comment: Maybe [*Mostly Harmless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless)? Lots of probability jokes in there there…

Comment: I'm reminded of the Casey & Andy comic strips from #247 http://www.galactanet.com/comic/view.php?strip=247 where Andy's position becomes uncertain and he phases through walls using that.